# Align content both top and bottom of the window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can't figure out how could I make that a in WPF that some content align to the top, and some to the bottom of the screen. Basically, I want to put two row of content on the top side of the window, and two on the bottom side. Note, I'm a beginner in WPF.

This is how I tried:

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <!-- some code here -->
   </StackPanel>

   <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
       <!-- some code here -->
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

But this doesn't work. What's the solution?

Comment: For me it doesn't. Could it be a problem that I have one Grid element in each StackPanel?

Comment: Use a `Grid` with appropriate row definitions (e.g. https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/ ) rather than a `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=net-5.0) for that. Using the [`Dock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.dock?view=net-5.0) attached property you can set the location of the child elements. The last element in the dock panel will occupy the remainig space. If you do not want that, you can set its [`LastChildFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill?view=net-5.0) property to `false`.

```
<DockPanel>
   <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <Button Content="Top 1" />
      <Button Content="Top 2" />
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
      <Button Content="Bottom 1" />
      <Button Content="Bottom 2" />
   </StackPanel>
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Or even simpler without the `StackPanel`s.

```
<DockPanel>
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Top 1" />
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Top 2" />
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Bottom 1" />
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Bottom 2" />
   <TextBlock Text="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The result looks like this.

[image: DockPanel example]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. I haven't run this in VS yet so it might be slightly off

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
      // some code here
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
      //EMpty
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
      // some code here
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

means take up all the remaining space.

means just expand to fit the containing element